# Reseting zoom: only updates on pan?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stumped by what is blocking the reset here. After the `resetZoom()` function runs nothing happens until I pan the svg, then it snaps back to origin. Any ideas why this might happen?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/84d596go/2/

```
var svg = d3.select("div#nodegraph")
                    .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", "100%")
                        .attr("height", "100%")
                        .call(d3.zoom()
                                .scaleExtent([0.25, 5])
                                .on("zoom", function() {
                                    root.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
                                })
                        );


var root = svg.append('g');


root.append('circle')
                .attr("cx", 10)
                .attr("cy", 10)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("fill", "red");


var resetZoom = function() {
    var zoom = d3.zoom();
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

document.getElementById("resetZoomButton").onclick = resetZoom;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating another zoom behaviour inside `resetZoom`, just use the same one you passed the selection. First, declare it:

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.25, 5])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    root.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
  });
```

And then:

```
var svg = d3.select("div#nodegraph")
  .call(zoom);

var resetZoom = function() {
  svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.25, 5])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    root.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
  });

var svg = d3.select("div#nodegraph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .call(zoom);

var root = svg.append('g');

root.append('circle').attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 10).attr("fill", "red");

var resetZoom = function() {
  svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

document.getElementById("resetZoomButton").onclick = resetZoom;
```

```css
#nodegraph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodegraph">
</div>
<button id="resetZoomButton" onClick="resetZoom()">RESET</button>
```

Regarding your question...

> Any ideas why this might happen?

... this is happening because only the zoom behaviour inside the `call` has an `on` listener changing something.

Comment: Not only does this exactly correct my issue (https://jsfiddle.net/84d596go/3/), it is a very thorough answer and I now understand it so much better! Thank you thank you!